# No results being displayed if the character length is more than is 15 letters in Solr Search

Tags: solr, solrcloud

While working with Solr Search encountered one issue.

When a search query is single syllable/word greater than 15 characters we are getting no results.
But if the same search query is shortened to less than 15 characters then we are getting results.

**How can we increase the character limit to get search result in both the cases?**

**Case 1: Greater than 15 Characters**
`curl -XGET 'http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/query?debug=query&q=katanasmartwatch'`

Result:

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 0,
    "params": {
      "q": "katanasmartwatch",
      "debug": "query"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 0,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": []
  }
}
```

**Case 2: Less than 15 Characters**
`curl -XGET 'http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/query?debug=query&q=katanasmartwatc'`

Result

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 0,
    "params": {
      "q": "katanasmartwatc",
      "debug": "query"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [{...}]
  }
}
```

Comment: This will depend on the analysis chain for the field you're searching against; are you searching against a field that have a ngramfilter attached, where the max token length is set to 14/15? (queries are usually issued against `/select`, so I'm guessing your `/query` endpoint has predefined settings for which fields to search against).